# Phonegap: Barcode Scanner not working consistently with iPhone5s

Tags: iphone, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I have developed an hybrid with combination of Sencha Touch2.3 and Phonegep. It has barcode scanner feature. It is working fine with iPhone 3 and iPhone 4. It is not working consistently in iPhone 5s. Sometimes it scans immediately and doesn't scan full the barcode.

I am sure there weren't problems with Sencha Touch 2.3 and I am using latest version of PhoneGap.

I don't know how to fix this. I tried looking in google, I could not find any useful answers.

--Sridhar

Comment: Now, I am having issue with Android phone also. My app is running in Android 4+ devices. I am using Phonegap 3.3.

Comment: @please make sure that you are using latest phone gap version.

Comment: @motto, I am using 3.3 and I am using barcode scanner 2.0.0 version.

Comment: sometimes it could be alert popup. could you please test this https://www.dropbox.com/s/s5vgwz9cov2ip91/ios.zip?dl=0 if it works i can send you original phone gap files.

Comment: also please include config.xml and index.html files too in your question and did you installed plug-ins via cmd or terminal ?